# Help finding local extrema of $f(x)=\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}-3\sin\frac{x}{2}$

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, optimization

> Find the local extrema of $f(x)=\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{2}}-3\sin\dfrac{x}{2}$ on the interval $0 \leq x \leq 2\pi$

$f^{\prime}=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}-3\cos \left(\dfrac{x}{2}\right) \left ( \dfrac{1}{2}\right )$

$f^{\prime}=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}-\dfrac{3\cos(x/2)}{2}$

To find critical points: $0=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}-\dfrac{3\cos\left(\dfrac{x}{2}\right)}{2}$

$-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}=-\dfrac{3\cos\left(\dfrac{x}{2}\right)}{2}$

$-\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{2}}=-{3\cos\left(\dfrac{x}{2}\right)}$

$\dfrac{2}{3\sqrt{2}}=\cos\left(\dfrac{x}{2}\right)$

$x= ???$

I don't know how to solve from here for the critical points. I have the answers but don't know how to get them. Can you please explain/show steps on what to do from here? Thank you.

Comment: I would recommend reviewing how to solve trigonometric equations at a site like http://www.sosmath.com/algebra/solve/solve0/solvtrig.html

Comment: The OP has indicated at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/629653/how-to-solve-frac23-sqrt2-cos-left-fracx2-right that the answers are supposed to be $x=0$, $3\pi/4$, and $2\pi$.  The $0$ and $2\pi$ make sense, but the $3\pi/4$ suggests the OP -- or *someone* -- has somehow gotten the wrong formula for $f(x)$.

Answer (score 2):

Now you can use $\cos x=2\cos^2 \frac{x}{2}-1=2(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{3})^2-1=2(\frac{2}{9})-1=-\frac{5}{9}$, so

$x=\cos^{-1}(-\frac{5}{9})=\pi-\cos^{-1}\frac{5}{9}$.

(Notice that $0\le\frac{x}{2}\le\pi\;\;$, so $\cos\frac{x}{2}>0\implies0<\frac{x}{2}<\frac{\pi}{2}\implies0<x<\pi$.)

Answer (score 1):

In your other post, I answered the question related to the solution of the equation which corresponds to a zero value of the derivative of your function. As I told you, the analytical solution is x = 2 ArcCos[Sqrt[2]/3] and I showed how to obtain the numerical solution. If you plug this value in your function, comes, after some simplifications from definitions, the value of -Sqrt[7] + Sqrt[2] ArcCos[Sqrt[2]/3] which is approximatly -1.11852. If you establish the second derivative of your function, you get f''= 3/4 Sin[x/2] which is positive for the range 0 < x < 2 Pi under consideration. So, your extremum is a minimum.